# Mysql 8.0: High CPU Usage

Tags: mysql, cpu-usage

We are using mysql 8.0 and also running 5.7 in some environment. We found our mysql 5.7 running fine on mostly environment but we are facing high CPU usage for 8.0. I didn't find anything in slow_query_logs, show processlist, persistent connections removed from PHP.

Same database dump working fine on mysql 5.7. I would really appreciate your quick suggestions.

Is mysql 8.0 is stable for live/production? please also share your thoughts.

Comment: You are using 8.0 and 5.7 in the same machine?

Comment: no. we are using on different machines with same OS configuration.

Comment: what does `show full processlist` reports when the cpu is on high load?

Comment: 5 active commands which run less than 1 sec and then nothing active.

Comment: This issue is very strange, thats why i didn't see any good suggestion. Do you feel its a OS issue like compatibility, configuration etc.

Comment: I am having higher cpu usage and loads on Mysql 8.0 too compared to Mysql 5.7. Same mysql settings, same OS version.

Comment: same for us. Multiple database replication and load balancing. High load only found in MySQL 8.0 machines. Any solution?

Comment: You may want to scan through this documentation for clues on CPU utilization. The default character set has changed from latin1 to utf8mb4. Has additional space required for table storage - affects CPU usage, as well.  The URL is  https://severalnines.com/blog/moving-mysql-57-mysql-80-what-you-should-know/